# Symbolic Links in Apache not working as expected

Tags: macos, wordpress, apache, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to get a symbolic link working in Apache on Mac OS X (Mountain Lion).

When I go to the folder containing the link in my browser, Apache sees the link as a file rather than a folder. If I click it, my browser attempts to download the link as a file.

Additionally, if I go to actual link in the browser, I get a message informing me I am not authorised.

I made the link in terminal using 'ln -s'.

Can anyone help me, this is very frustrating.

Context:

Developing a Wordpress theme, want the theme to be in a different directory than the usual Wordpress themes directory. Have seen it done in this way before, however I've been unsuccessful in achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.

Firstly apache may not have permissions to read and execute the directory you have symlinked.

or alternatively it could be that your Apache is not configured to follow symbolic links

If your .htaccess file is permitted to override options then you can try adding this to your .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Otherwise you will need to change your Apache config file.